# May I be able to post questions again I have read a bit on framing questions properly?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I know my one question received negative votes but I will try to maintain question level according to MSE. May I please be able to post questions?

Comment: As the tooltip for the downvote says, _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_. Improving the quality of your questions, showing solutions, showing attempts to find the answer through links and so on can help avoid this.

Comment: Also, this is not supposed to be a [feature-request] question but a [discussion]. However, this may also be off-topic as it is too specific and does not help generally.

Comment: I see i edited Sir

Comment: I don't think you get banned for a single question with one net downvote and no close votes. Did you have some other questions that got closed and deleted (so they don't show up when I look at your profile)?

Comment: Yeah one was deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I can't grant you the ability to ask questions again Orion, I can give you some advice that will make it easier to ask them in the future, should you regain this ability. An example to focus on is one of your questions I edited, which had two problems that could be areas of improvement:

**Screenshots of text**

The first problem is that you included a quote of your textbook in the form of a screenshot. Mathematics Stack Exchange prefers users to write their questions in MathJax instead of this.

If you are lazy like me, and do not want to write the whole thing out, I recommend an image to Latex tool, such as [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/#downloads). All you have to do with such tools is [highlight the part of the textbook you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TGOa.jpg), and it will generate latex to reproduce it.

[image]

**Readability**

The other problem with your question was your use of language. This is a harder problem to solve, and I would recommend checking what you have written in something like Microsoft Word for the built in grammar checker. In addition, the title of your question "Whats the text meant to say by comparison with |x-2| slower faster thing?" doesn't describe the problem very well, and while it was answerable by the community, it will not necessarily be found by other people googling a similar problem, which is one of the main purposes of this site.

Comment: Pictures of any kind, if images, are not a good fit on main.  They can be helpful on meta, if a user suspects a bug, e.g..