# Asking questions from a long proof

Tags: support

There is a proof from a book I have a doubt on, but the proof itself is quite long. Should I copy paste the whole text or can I just take screen shot from the pages in the book and put?

Comment: Neither.  Isolate the part of the proof you doubt and any required background information and provide a reference to the book you found it in.  Be considerate to the people you're asking for help from :)

Comment: The issue is, I am not sure if the ideas could be made to make  sense like that because this book is somewhat obscure.. at least from the undergraduate prespective (who seem to be the largest population of this site) @postmortes

Comment: Ok.  I confess I don't understand why you want an undergraduate to answer you, but that is your choice :)

Comment: What I meant is not exactly about the educational qualification but it is that this book's knowledge is not common. As someone with undergraduate experience I can say it is not , maybe for masters it is not as well. I am not sure.

Comment: Who are you trying to get an answer from, if not an expert?

Comment: Welp, anyone who has enough ability to answer my Q. Turns out the book's pdf is hosted by some German uni on the internet. I've linked that in [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425968/details-in-existence-of-free-groups-proof-clara-loeh-pg-22-23)

Comment: My answer on the following page might be helpful here. I show how to automatically convert screenshots to latex. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/may-i-be-able-to-post-questions-again-i-have-read-a-bit-on-framing-questions-pro/34365#34365

Answer (score 10):

You should transcribe the part of the proof you are confused about into MathJax, instead of taking screenshot, since screen-shots are not searchable. Then, if there are any terms in the section you transcribed whose definitions appear elsewhere in the paper, you should also transcribe their definitions from the paper into your question. Finally, try your best to explain what you are confused about.

If this is too much work, then it means that your question cannot be appropriately answered on MSE.