# Is there an application where you can visually input LaTeX and have it translate to a code that works in Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I do not know if this question is appropriate to the Mathematics Meta. This question may be closed if it isn't.

But I would like to ask if there is an application people can refer me to that can visually put equations similar to Office, which can be converted into LaTeX. I know some people would tell me that I should just learn LaTeX manually and that maybe it isn't hard. But for the sake of curiosity, I would want to ask if such an application exists. I would find it easier to just visually input an equation and then convert it to LaTeX.

Comment: Yes there is, see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/may-i-be-able-to-post-questions-again-i-have-read-a-bit-on-framing-questions-pro/34365#34365

Comment: I think I'll post a seperate answer to your question since the previous is primarily on another topic and hard to search for.

Comment: You can also look at older posts here tagged [mathjax+editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+editor), such as: [Latex editor suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5053), [WYSIWYG for math formulas?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127),  or [MathJax WYSIWYG Editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12967) and [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/12967).

Answer (score 10):

Note that the software on Math.SE is called [MathJax](https://mathjax.org/), which is heavily inspired or even based on [$\mathrm\LaTeX$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), but not 100% compatible.

AFAIK, Mathpix of [the answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34710/80734) of user400188 outputs $\mathrm\LaTeX$ which is sometimes also MathJax; other times, it will require you to know how MathJax on this site works as well (for instance `\(...\)` should be changed to `$...$`)

That said here are some other software (no affiliation):

1. **[Detexify:](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)** This allows you to mouse-draw a symbol, and it will give you the code. Only works one symbol at a time though. And again, this outputs $\mathrm \LaTeX$, which may not be MathJax. See also [Symbols in use on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/symbols-in-use-on-this-site/26084#26084)  and other [search results for Detexify on math.meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=&q=detexify&mixed=0)
2. **[Lyx:](https://www.lyx.org/)** I've never used this, but it is supposed to be a user-friendly GUI that converts to $\mathrm\LaTeX$ (a full compilable document). [Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiDFyIuloy4) I found googling, and a screenshot from the video [showing the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh337.jpg).
3. **[mathcha.io:](https://www.mathcha.io/)** I use this primarily to make diagrams due to the export to TikZ feature, but it also exports to $\mathrm\LaTeX$. Typing `$` then `\` brings up a menu which should be helpful for people not yet familiar with $\mathrm\LaTeX$. It also has [a Detexify-like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90qq2.png) feature; when you're done, the "Latex" button in the top-right gives you the $\mathrm\LaTeX$ code for that equation.

Finally, since you mention Office, I'll link to [this TeX.SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document) where they discuss how to get $\mathrm\LaTeX$ output from Word.

Comment: I'd add that in LyX you can copy the math entered to get the LaTeX directly in your clipboard, no need to export to a file and copy from there.

Answer (score 7):

An application which takes [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TGOa.jpgs) of equations and text, and converts them into [Latex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLTtq.pngs), exists and is called [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com).

Mathpix is [trialware](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trialware) which used to be open source, but (at time of edit) just allows you [10 snippets a month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4lj3.png) and asks you to pay if you want more. At the time of editing, it is a good option for this application.

Here is an example of its use:

[image]
[image]

It also works on [handwriting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmQL.png).

Comment: I'll mention other posts where Mathpix was mentioned: [Mathpix Snip Tool: Automatic $\LaTeX$ code generation from typed or handwritten math!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31106/), [What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31182/). I suggested Mathpix for a different reason (exporting to Word) [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/how-to-copy-paste-a-mathematics-stack-exchange-answer-to-word/34178#34178)

Comment: It might also be good to mention that it [works better than (I) expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmQL.png)  on handwriting

Comment: @CalvinKhor I still haven't found it reliable enough to use on handwriting, but then again, that could just be my handwriting...

Comment: Yes, my above screenshot has errors. But It works even better when I write nicely :)

Comment: Where can I find the original open source version of Mathpix?

Comment: @Cactus, I would like to, but I have never been able to find it since they started charging.

Answer (score 3):

[MathType](https://www.wiris.com/en/mathtype/) is the equation editor that was used in MS Office for many years, and the latest one uses some similar ideas.

MathType lets you build equations visually, and can then output them in several different forms, including MS Office graphics, TeX/LaTeX, MathML, etc. There is no specific option to output the MathJax format used on this site, but the LaTeX format will work in most cases.

Comment: +1; IIRC MathType is now subscription-only